# How to emulate a ctrl sequence with `system()`?

Tags: c, linux, parameters, command-line-interface, terminal-emulator

If I use CTRL + A CTRL + K in the terminal (LINUX), it clears the line I type out in terminal. I want to perform this function through a `system()` call in my code. What parameters do I pass to a `system()` in order for it to run CTRL + A CTRL + K?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `system()` if you just want to clear the current line as output by *your application* and move cursor to the beginning; instead just use `printf`. The code `\r` means carriage return, and moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, and the ANSI escape sequence `CSI 2 K` will clear the entire line - the CSI consists of 2 characters: ASCII ESC (`\033`), and `[`.

Thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Here be demo");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\r\033[2KIt works!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very likely trying to do something wrong.

First a minor note that you can clear up the line with mere ^U. ^K removes stuff from the current position and ^A takes you to the beginning, kind of a round-about way of doing this.

Most programs should not accept interactive input, but instead take arguments from the command line (the argc and argv stuff). In the unlikely case the program has to be interactive, you typically don't want to do any explicit screen manipulation. In the even more unlikely case it makes sense to do said manilupation, you want to use something like ncurses.

That said, I strongly suggest you elaborate on your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense, but you can use Ctrl+A Ctrl+K in `system()` by crafting a command that allocates a PTY, runs a readline command like `bash`, and then write ASCII 0x01 0x0B to it. `script` and `printf` lets you do this:

```
void main() {
  system(
      "{ sleep 1; "
      "echo -n 'part of a line. deleting with Ctrl+A Ctrl+K soon...'; "
      "sleep 3; "
      "printf '\x01\x0b'; "
      "sleep 2; "
      "} | script -q 'bash'"
      );
}
```

This will show a bash prompt, simulate writing "part of a line..", and then it writes Ctrl-A Ctrl-K to it, deleting it.

Make sure to try it verbatim without any changes, because it can't be adapted to do anything useful in a larger program.

PS: If you want to write and overwrite a line to create a spinner or progress bar, the question you should ask is "how do I write and overwrite a line to create a spinner or progress bar?"

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. suspicion that they just want to make some kind of a progress bar or a spinner may be the correct one and has a reasonable/trivial answer, which you chose not to provide. Instead, you provided an obviously insane code sample implementing OP's wrong idea and now risk that they will building something on top of it.

Comment: Technically correct is the best kind of correct ^__^

Answer (score -3):

First check the terminal controlling sequence what these commands give. You can do this by pressing a CTRL + V before the command. You will likely get

```
^A^K
```

If you want to do this with a `system()` call, then you should have to call a command with it, which ejects this terminal controlling sequence to your screen. Simplest command is for that the `/bin/echo`. A

```
/bin/echo -ne '^A^K'
```

will do the same. Give it to the `system()`:

```
system("/bin/echo -ne '^A^K'");
```

And wonder.

Comment: I tried this, this just printed out "^A^K" to my command line

Comment: @Aria This is the `-e` of the `echo` is for. It is the abbreviation of *evaluate*.

Comment: Wait, it this line clear is the feature of your shell or terminal emulator, then it will be really not so easy! But give it a try. If it doesn't work, the next step will be to find out, what does this line deletion feature.

Comment: `echo -e` does not work with caret notation, and writing these characters to screen will not affect bash's line reading.

Comment: @thatotherguy 1. Try then `echo -e` and you will see that it works. 2. It is a different (sub-)question, what will this sequence do. In the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179486/how-to-emulate-a-ctrl-sequence-with-system/45179516#comment77327648_45179516) I explained, it won't surely work. 3. I don't know what makes the line deletion for this sequence, the bash (i.e. readline) or anything, the OP didn't write it.

Comment: @thatotherguy  4. Referencing the comment again, my next idea is to watch, what will the readline (bash) do for this shortcut, likely it will produce an additional list of control sequences. The next step would be to check what is this sequence (for example, with a `strace`) and then emitting this from `echo -e`. 5. To do (4), first a feedback from the OP is needed, how the things are working by him. 6. It is also possible that this whole thing won't work, but I think it is unlikely (newer terminals are far enough smart to do this with control sequences, the only question is what is it).